# JPQL query with many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

We have 2 entities Technology and Project with a Many-to-Many relationship, which are linked
with an additional reference table.

```
technologies
 id      name
1000 | digging
2000 | drilling

projects
id    name
10 | London
20 | Madrid

technologies_projects
tech_id     project_id
1000     | 10
2000     | 10
1000     | 20
```

I can retreive Technology from db with such a query:

```
@Query("select t from Technology t left join fetch t.projects")
List<Technology> findAll();
```

JPQL query with `left join fetch` clause must be used to retreive Technology with collection of projects to avoid lazy initialization exception.

**The question is:** How must the query be modified do get the list of technologies, used in a certain project? (the query `findAllByProject(10)` must return technologies 1000 and 2000).

I cannot use native SQL query here because I need `join fetch` to get collection of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a where clause on project entity.

```java
@Query("select t from Technology t left join fetch t.projects p where p.id=10")
List<Technology> findAllByProject10();
```